# How do I select only the objects with a different key in this jQuery collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[Object, Object, Object, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[3], context: undefined]
  0: Object
    1: 1
    2: 2
    3: 7
   __proto__: Object
  1 : Object
    1: 6
    2: 2
    3: 5
    6: 15
    __proto__: Object
  2 : Object
    1: 3
    2: 2
    3: 5
    5: 7
    __proto__: Object
  context: undefined
  length: 3
  prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[3]
  __proto__: jQuery[0]
```

You'll notice that each object has the same following **keys: 1,2,3**

But second object has a **key: 6** and the third object has a **key: 5**

I need to select these keys (or key/value pairs).

How can I do that? I'm open to using libraries if there is a good one.

Comment: jQuery collection? Why does your jQuery object have something other than DOM elements? And what's preventing you from reading those properties like you'd do in any other situation? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Nathan Can include `json` representation of object within `jQuery` wrapper at Question ?

Comment: Well, the reason this is a jQuery object is because I'm iterating over JSON data in various ways to arrive at this collection and I'm wrapping it in jQuery at times to use the jQuery iterators. I now need to accomplish what I'm asking for in the question. I don't know if posting the original JSON data structure would be helpful as I'm needing to parse it in multiple ways to arrive at this collection.

Comment: @Nathan _"I don't know if posting the original JSON data structure would be helpful "_ To reproduce the object accurately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are using JQuery in a wrong way. There should be DOM Objects in your JQuery Object and if you look at the context property in your JQuery object it says undefined..

Besides this, to filter by key and value equality I suggest following:

```
var yourCollection = [{1:1, 2:2, 3:7}, 
                      {1:6, 2:2, 3:5, 6:15}, 
                      {1:3, 2:2, 3:5, 5:7}];
yourCollection.forEach(function(item){
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(property){
      if(parseInt(property, 10) % item[property] === 0){
        delete item[property];
      }
    })
})
```

Output is:

```
[[object Object] {
 3: 7
}, [object Object] {
 1: 6,
 3: 5,
 6: 15
}, [object Object] {
 1: 3,
 3: 5,
 5: 7
}]
```

EDIT: Filter collection by symmetric difference. You said you would agree using a lib, so I suggest using lodash (utility lib).

```
var yourCollection = [{1:1, 2:2, 3:7}, 
                      {1:6, 2:2, 3:5, 6:15}, 
                      {1:3, 2:2, 3:5, 5:7}];


var keyMap = _.map(yourCollection, function(item){
  return _.map(Object.keys(item), function(property){
    return parseInt(property, 10);
  })
})

var reducedKeyMap = _.xor(_.flatten(_.initial(keyMap)), _.last(keyMap));

var symmetricDifference = [];
symmetricDifference = _.reduce(yourCollection, function(result, next, index, collection){
  var substrat = _.pick(next, reducedKeyMap);
  if(!_.isEmpty(substrat)){
    result.push(substrat);
  }
  return result;
}, [])

document.write(JSON.stringify(symmetricDifference));
```

Output is:

```
[{"6":15},{"5":7}]
```

[Running example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPYwMa)

Comment: _"using JQuery in a wrong way. There should be DOM Objects in your JQuery Object"_ `jQuery()` should be able to accept an object , or array of objects as parameter ?

Comment: Yes you can, but why should you do that? The only reason I see is misusing JQuery as utility man. One could chip in with browser compatibility using $.each, but I think JQuery should not serve as "es-shim"

Comment: This is close... and you're right. I've just not had a lot of JS experience but this works cleanly without the jQuery noise. Only thing in this solution is that you're returning more than what I want. I just want those with different keys. So the return value should only be [{6:15}, {5:7}].

Comment: Also, is there a similar way to get identical matches? For example, only {2:2} matches all the objects.

Comment: Okay yes I see, I only filtered by key/value equality, updating soon

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by getting identical matches, but if you want to get all objects which have a 2:2 key/value, you can use _.filter like:
_.filter(yourCollection, {2:2})

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I've also learned to avoid needlessly using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a nested loop and match the keys.

```js
var arr = [
{ 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 7 },
{ 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 5, 6: 15 },
{ 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 5, 5: 7 },
];
var output = document.getElementById('output');
for(var x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
    for(var key in arr[x]){
        var keysToAvoid = ['1','2','3'];
        if(keysToAvoid.indexOf(key) == -1){
           output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + arr[x][key] + '<br>'; //gotcha!
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But second object has a **key: 6** and the third object has a **key: 5**
>
> I need to select these keys (or key/value pairs).

Try creating an array `keys` containing properties within object to be filtered , utilizing `.map()` , `Object.keys()` , `.slice()` , `.splice()`, `.indexOf()` to filter property keys of `obj` ; `.filter()` to remove `undefined` values `.get()` to convert return value from jQuery object to `Array` ; call `.map()` on `obj` when `keys` defined to return array of filtered values

```js
var obj = $([{
  1: 2,
  2: 2,
  3: 7
}, {
  1: 6,
  2: 2,
  3: 5,
  6: 15
}, {
  1: 3,
  2: 5,
  3: 5,
  5: 7
}]);
// But second object has a key: 6 and the third object has a key: 5
var keys = $(obj).map(function(index, value) {
  // return array of property keys from `obj`
  return Object.keys(value)
}).get().map(function(v, k, arr) {
  // `j`: copy of original array of property keys from `obj`,
  // `i`: current value `v` removed from `j` utilizing `k` index
  var j = arr.slice(), i = j.splice(k, 1)[0];
  // if copy of `arr` `j` does not contain `v` a duplicate entry of `v`,
  // return `i`: `v` removed from `j`, else return `null` 
  return j.indexOf(v) === -1 ? i : null
}).filter(Boolean) // `["6", "5"]`
// return array of values , where item within `keys` property of 
// an object within `obj` 
, res = $(obj).map(function(key, val) {
    var i = Object.keys(val).filter(function(v, k) {
      return keys.indexOf(v) !== -1
    })[0];
    return val[i];
}).get();
// do stuff with `res`
document.write(res); // from `obj` property, value `6:15` , `5:7` : `15, 7`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Mm.. How are you setting the "keys" variable? My problem is I don't know how to extract the keys in the objects that are uniq.

Comment: If you only know the keys that are always there (1,2,3), you can alter the code slightly

`var keys = ["1", "2", "3"];` and `return keys.indexOf(v) == -1`

Comment: @Nathan _"How are you setting the "keys" variable"_ -> See OP at _"But second object has a key: 6 and the third object has a key: 5"_  `keys` array contains `"5"`, `"6"` . _"how to extract the keys in the objects that are uniq"_ not appear at Question ?

Comment: Well, that just happens to be the case in this collection.. but the collection is dynamic, so I'm never sure which keys will be uniq. That's really the point of the whole post. I need to programmatically find them.